# Building JavaScript bundle: error (Cannot find module)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo

C:\Users\x\OneDrive\Desktop\yarntest\weather\node_modules@expo\vector-icons\fonts\Entypo.ttf: Cannot find module 'C%3A%5CUsers%5x%5COneDrive%5CDesktop%5Cyarntest%5Cweather%5Cnode_modules%5Cexpo%5Ctools%5ChashAssetFiles.js'
Require stack:

- C:\Users\x\OneDrive\Desktop\yarntest\weather\node_modules\metro\src\Assets\index.js
- C:\Users\x\OneDrive\Desktop\yarntest\weather\node_modules\metro\src\assetTransformer.js
- C:\Users\x\OneDrive\Desktop\yarntest\weather\node_modules\metro\src\JSTransformer\worker\index.js
- C:\Users\x\OneDrive\Desktop\yarntest\weather\node_modules\metro\node_modules\jest-worker\build\child.js

Building JavaScript bundle: error

I am unable to resolve this error. Pls have a look. I checked it, module is present, but not working.

Comment: I don't think there is enough information here for anyone to help you.

Answer (score 0):

It was problem of previous react Native. Latest version works